# What's the use of the derived class as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, terminology, crtp, static-polymorphism

What's the purpose of this pattern? What is it called? It looked very strange when I saw it the first time, though I have now seen it many times.

```
template<typename Derived>
struct Base {
  //...
};

struct Example : Base<Example> {
  //...
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are reffering to [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). Also refer [here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=yQU-NlmQb_UC&pg=PA295&lpg=PA295&dq=CRTP+david+vandevoorde&source=bl&ots=EdpM35_yHZ&sig=cgcBckX0b2a5KRgZtZmSLzewcjY&hl=en&ei=crnHTN2IIIicvgOm4d3ODw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: @Thomson Tan: Note carefully about @GMan's point about static polymorphism. That's an important point. It provides for simulating virtual function calls from the base class without the overhead of virtual functions (if that is important)

Answer (score 10):

It's called the [Curiously Recurring Template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) pattern, and allows for static polymorphism.

It's useful when you want to add functionality to a specific class, but want the utility to be usable in a generic case. By making the utility dependent on and use a template parameter, you can achieve both.

Answer (score 6):

[Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), or CRTP as we [call it](http://bitbucket.org/kniht/scraps/src/104d8782bb83/cpp/kniht/crtp.hpp).

Comment: First answer by 4 seconds; you guys are slacking!